# Xamarin gives error but it works in vs 2013

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin

```
Resource.Id.textView1 = d.ToString();
```

It doesn't accept this. Why ? What can i do ? I tried to writing just id of textview but the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Any exception or error message?

Comment: Is `textView1` a variable of type `String`?

Comment: No it's not defined in main.cs. It is just in the ui.xml file. So should i define it as a string ?

Comment: Does the textView1 have `Text` property? In that case try assigning `textView1.Text = d.ToString()`

Comment: OK it works but when i defined textview in code. I defined that ui element by this code : TextView textView1 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1); is it true ? (my textview's id is textView1 in xml file)

Comment: You *need* a reference to your View in order to be able to set property values on it through the code (i.e. `Text`), and yes, the correct way of going about obtaining a reference to a View defined inside your axml is by using your `Activity`'s `FindViewById<TView>(int)` and passing in the integer ID of the view you're looking for (which in your case is defined as `Resource.Id.textView1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var textView = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

textView.Text = d.ToString();
```

I am making the assumption here that what you're really trying to do is setting the value of the `Text` property of your `TextView` defined in your axml as `textView1`.

Your `Resource.Id.textView1` is *not* an actual reference to the `TextView` you're trying to work with - it's just an integer ID of the view. You obtain the reference to the actual `TextView` by using `FindViewById` in your `Activity` subclass.